# Detecting if widget is overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I would like to change the red widget's position according to the blue ones.

Case 1:
*If blue list widget's height is smaller than screen height, locate the red one to bottom of the screen.*

case 2:
*If blue list widget's height is higher than screen height, locate the red one to just bottom of the widget.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something involving a list seems too complicated, it's often interesting to look into [slivers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers).

For your case one sliver just solves your issue: [SliverFillRemaining](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html)

Here is an example implementation for your issue, largely inspired by the code given by the flutter team.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber[300],
                height: 150.0,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green[300],
                height: 150.0,
              ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied,
              size: 75,
              color: Colors.blue[900],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```